# Receiving error when clicking buttons in Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot in Microsoft Teams which is communicating with a Bot Service in Azure built on Bot Framework. Everything, including clicking buttons, worked perfectly on my own machine.

Then a colleague of mine tried it. He could ask questions to the bot just fine, but when he tried to click a button an error appeared in the chat window:

"Something went wrong, please try again".

Looking in the console, we can see the error:

"Invoke failed due to internal error: Invoke failed: something went wrong in ProcessInvoke"

The error message appear on the very first request when calling "Invoke".

I've tried reinstalling the bot.

I've tried clearing cache/using different browser, but the problem seem to follows the user and not the browser.

This would suggest there is a user permission problem (though I wouldn't see why), but we've also tried to elevate privileges of the user without success.

The bot was created in App Studio, then downloaded as a zip and installed using "Upload custom app" in the Teams Apps Store, and made available to a specific Team.

Comment: This is very interesting. Is it *just* the Teams channel? (my assumption is yes). Just curious if he can click the buttons in another channel like WebChat. What are the buttons? Suggested actions? Is the bot based off of a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples)? Is the bot configured for group chat; if so, does the behavior change for him within a group chat with you and the bot?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! Turned out to be a bug introduced and now fixed by Microsoft as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be the same issue as explained in this thread:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Bot-messageback-issue-in-1-1/td-p/678322

Microsoft has fixed this issue, and the bot now work as expected.